# Is "his husband" valid?

Tags: dictionaries, errors, sociolinguistics

I was surprised to see "his husband" in the [Cambridge dictionary’s entry for *compliment*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/compliment):

> [image: picture of Cambdige Dictionary definition of compliment]

> *He complained that **his husband** never paid him any compliments anymore.*

Isn't that a mistake? Or is Cambridge talking about something homosexual?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81548/discussion-on-question-by-1c13-yeung-sin-chun--1c13-is-his-husband-gramma).

Comment: Not sure why you made this a question about grammar. From the standpoint of grammar, "his X" is equally corrrect for absolulely any noun you replace X with.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Because I wanted it to be about the English language.

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but look at these two sentences: *At night I heard a dog bark* versus *At mathematics I heard a smell glow*. They have the same structure and hence are both grammatically correct (or both incorrect, but they are indeed correct). So, why do you think should *her husband* be valid, but *his husband* not, if *his* and *her* have the same grammatical function?

Comment: In English, there is no grammatical gender on nouns, so there is no grammatical agreement. That is, grammatically speaking, 'his husband' is just fine. One might have semantic problems with it, if you think of males as not allowed to have husbands, but that is a semantic/cultural thing that is out side of grammar. In contrast, adjectives _do_ agree with nouns for number, so 'two bird' is ungrammatical (both the noun and adjective would have the same singular or plural grammar. Number agreement is enforced in the grammar.

Comment: In languages with grammatical gender and gender agreement, you have to say, for example in French, 'son mari', (the person's husband), where 'son' corresponds to his or her, and 'mari' to husband. But even though 'son' is grammatically masculine, it doesn't specify the gender of the referent, just the grammatical gender of the following noun. There may be one, but I don't know of any society and language where the family marriageability patterns are reflected in grammatical agreement in the language.

Comment: I notice you edited the title to remove 'grammatically'. Does that mean you really mean something in addition to syntax or even not syntax at all? You till have 'grammaticality' as a tag.

Comment: I originally didn't mean to ask whether it is grammatically correct but obviouslyI asked it in a wrong way. I actually wanted to know whether "his" can be used to refer to women, or "husband"  can be used to refer to "wife", or this is just an unintended mistake. And my problem was solved already.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The answer to the question “Is ‘his husband’ valid?” (in the English language) is “Yes, yes it is” — although as the OED notes, the word *husband* was historically...

> > Used exclusively with reference to mixed-sex marriages **until the late 20th cent.**, and in this context taken as correlative to *wife*.

So that must be how you were thinking of it. However, we’re now **past** the late 20th century, and other uses exist.

Moreover, the first citation for ‘his husband’ in the OED’s entry for ***husband*** is from more than four hundred years ago in 1602, so it can hardly be called a uniquely recent collocation. But see the indented note in each of the three entries below:

> 2a. The (or a) male partner in a marriage; esp. a married man considered in relation to his spouse. Also fig. of Christ in his relationship to the Church or to an individual soul.
>
> > Used exclusively with reference to mixed-sex marriages until the late 20th cent., and in this context taken as correlative to *wife*.
>
> - 2001   *Newsweek* (Nexis) 4 June 18
>      Last April Wabeke and Swinkels were married, **husband and husband**, under the new Dutch law.
> - 2013   *Vanity Fair* June 113/1 
>     A woman is killed by her husband, her boyfriend, or her **same-sex partner**.
>
> 2b. In other (esp. same-sex) relationships in which the two partners are regarded as occupying roles analogous to those in a traditional mixed-sex marriage: the person assuming the role regarded as more stereotypically masculine, i.e. as being equivalent to that of the husband (sense 2a). Cf. wife n. 7a.
>
> > Earliest with reference to the ‘marriages’ with male favourites allegedly entered into by some Roman emperors. In later use often with reference to relationships between male prison inmates.
>
> - 1602   T. North tr. S. Goulart *Lives Epaminondas, Philip of Macedon* 109
>      He [*sc*. the emperor Nero] maried one Pythagoras as **his husband**.
> - 1664   E. Leigh *Analecta Caesarum Romanorum* 230
>      He [*sc*. Helagabalus] so favoured Aurelius Zoticus, that himself commanded him to be taken..for the Emperors husband.
> - 1761   J. Mills tr. J. B. L. Crevier *Hist. Rom. Emperors* VIII. xxiii. 255   
>   **His** [*sc*. Helagabalus'] **husband** was one Hierocles, originally a Carian slave.
> - 1966   *Transition* 27 33/1
>      One partner..was put in the punishment cells. **His ‘husband’** could not get to him.
> - 2004   M. Epprecht *Hungochani* 94 
>     Because of a moral obligation to provide for all of their wyfies fairly..most prison husbands remain serially monogamous.

Today *husband* is also used in a more inclusive way:

> 2c. Used to denote either partner in a (generally long-term) relationship between two men.
>
> > Here referring to a relationship other than a marriage, or (in later use) to a relationship regardless of whether or not it is a marriage. For uses explicitly referring to men who are married to one another see sense 2a.
>
> - 1946   J. Vining Diary 23 Aug. in *Gay Diary* (1980) II. 1
>      There's someone on the phone..and he wants to know if **his husband’s** here.
> - 1957   *Jet* 5 Dec. 42   
>   One of the effeminate male owners [of the shop] slapped a guest for making a pass at **his ‘husband’**.
> - 1994   *Advocate* 28 June 71/3
>      I thought of course I would take my lover [to the party], whom I refer to as my husband, since I find the word lover far too personal.
> - 2007   J. Perez *Soulfully Gay* iv. 183
>      Harvey..lives in Las Vegas with **his husband**.

Notice how some earlier uses put ‘scare quotes’ around the word *husband*, but how the later ones do not. This is an indication of the writer’s acceptance of the term used in this way as the male partner of a male, or at least of that writer’s perception of how the word will be understood by the reader.

---

#### A Cautionary Note for Learners

As an English language learner, you should probably understand that the word *homosexual* you used in your question can carry clinical or pejorative connotations, and that the term *same-sex* may be less likely to do so.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81578/discussion-on-answer-by-tchrist-is-his-husband-grammatically-valid).

Answer (score 19):

In certain jurisdictions (27 countries in June 2018), same-sex marriages have the same legal status as different-sex ones. In these, which include the United Kingdom, in which Cambridge Dictionaries is based, a woman may therefore have a wife, and a man a husband.

[27 countries where same-sex marriages are legally recognised](https://abcnews.go.com/GMA/Culture/27-countries-sex-marriage-officially-legal/story?id=56041136)

Answer (score -11):

Yes, "his husband" is grammatically valid, based upon the etymology given below.

> Husband = Hus + band(House + bound.

Anglo and Saxon dictionary.

> From 'Bonda'>(binda = the verb to bind).
>   Bonda, an ; m. [bond bound, one bound by rules, from bindan to
>   bind] A husband, an householder, a master of a family.
>
> Hus = house.
>   Housebreak should be "Husbreak".
>
> Husbrec, hus-bryce house-break

Comment: Can you comment for the OP as to the grammaticality of using the word 'his' with this? All you've done is give an etymology of one word.

Comment: Mitch, without the etymology, how can you properly know a word?
Because of the given etymology, we can now see that all personal pronouns can be used. Never fight originality.

Comment: Sylomun, sure an etymology can help explain (but of course doesn't determine) meaning. But your answer doesn't connect yet with the OP's request. You just need to be explicit.

Comment: Mitch, I'm a professional man, and it's all about context. I'm sure, that some folks who don't have access to a 17th century dictionary would be glad. Knowledge is never wasted.

Comment: You're not saying anything wrong, but this is still not an answer for the OP and risks downvoting or deletion.

Comment: Mitch: Did you not comprehend my answer? What do you not understand?:
"Because of the given etymology, we can now see that all personal pronouns can be used. Never fight originality." – Sylomun Weah
Is "his" not a personal pronoun?

Comment: @SylomunWeah You just need to edit your answer post so that it *actually contains your answer*. As of now, you have given an answer to the question, but you haven't put it into your answer post.

Comment: I don't understand what a word’s etymology has to do with grammar.

Comment: tchrist: Do you have a problem with knowledge? Did you know that "grammar" also means "learning"?

Comment: @SylomunWeah You don't seem to have understood how the Stack Exchange question-and-answer model works. I encourage you to [visit our Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and also to [take our site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour). We are not a discussion site or a forum. We expect answers to be answers, not random "oh by the way here's this ancillary bit of trivia that doesn't address the question in any way" posts masquerading as answers when they are merely etymological copy-paste verbiage. Please stop doing that.

Comment: Thanks, but I thought that the content of a comment was an answer. I'll take the tour.